# Function to trigger select()

Tags: python

I would like to write a function in Python that triggers select() every 30 seconds.

So far my code looks like the following -

```
inputs = [ UDPSock , sys.stdin]
outputs = []
while inputs:
  readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs)
  for s in readable:
    if s is UDPSock
      # Deal with socket

    elif s is sys.stdin:
      # Deal with input
```

I would like to achieve something along the lines of -

```
inputs = [ UDPSock , sys.stdin, timer]
outputs = []
while inputs:
  readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs)
  for s in readable:
    if s is UDPSock
      # Deal with socket

    elif s is sys.stdin:
      # Deal with input

    elif s is timer:
      # Deal with  timer
```

Ideally I would like to this without the use of threading if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a problem with using the optional `timeout` parameter to [select](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html)?

e.g.

```
while True:
    ready = readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs,
                                                            inputs, 30.0)
        if not any(ready):
            #timeout condition
        else:
            #iterate over the ready lists as appropriate
```

Comment: @Fletch, if this helped you feel free to accept my answer (the tick buttons), to help others referencing this question in the future.